# How to disable web browsing on public PCs?

Tags: windows, browser

For a gaming center, How can I disable web browsing through any browser. But the PC should connect to the internet for online gameplay.

Comment: The 'simplest' route would be to block http/https going out however that _may_ affect some games which require those to connect (I don't know of any but that doesn't mean they exist) which you'd need to let through, otherwise you're looking at doing stateful packet inspection and blocking anything that isn't 'allowed'.

Comment: Someone told me about Linux + Firewall method. But I know just these terms. Nothing in detail...

Comment: Try proxy to block web browsing.

Comment: Just don't install a browser? And remove access rights from IE.

Comment: Use a group policy to only allow the applications you want to be ran, to be ran, thus making it impossible for anyone to run a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to configure the filtering in router, only allow connections to specific domains(URL which connects to online game-play) and deny remaining.

see below to configure the same in d-link router.

http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/mydlink-routers/dir-810l/how-do-i-set-up-website-filtering-on-my-router

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you could do, you could go the proxy way, or try to block webbrowser on clients or manage by a custom dns server. I would go the proxy way with linux and [dansguardian](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DansGuardian) but if you are not into linux servers you could prefere an appliance, like a phisical firewall, something like a zyxel should not be too expensive.